# jQuery - How to display a flash banner for 5 seconds once it has loaded fade it away?

Tags: jquery, css, flash

On my homepage, when I enter, I want only the flash to appear first while the rest of the content is being loaded in the background. Once the flash has loaded, display it for 5 seconds then fade out to reveal the content. Is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

#### Timeout

Start a timer ([`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)) once you've inserted the Flash banner object into your DOM tree, and after the timer ran out, you can remove the object.

There is one big problem with this solution, the Flash plugin may start slowly and your timer will run out before the banner was on the screen enough.

#### Callback function

You could create a callback function which you can call from your Flash banner, and then you can start the timer and remove the banner after the timer ran out (you need to use the [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) package).

This solution also has a disadvantages.

The Flash banner should be prepared to callback your function and you also need to pass the name of the callback function to your flash object, so this is a bit harder to implement.

If the user has no Flash player or blocked the Flash content the hide will never occur. So you also need a fallback timer, which will remove the Flash object and shows your page after a longer period.

Comment: I solved my problem by setting a timer with jquery once the page has loaded. After 5 seconds, I fade the flash banner away and fadein the content. Thanks :D